# Include embedded in Maven javaFX project While Deploy an applicaiton

Tags: java, maven, deployment, javafx

I have a javaFX Maven project structured like so:

```
BaseDir_
        |--src_
        |       |-- Main
        |       |       |-- java
        |       |       |-- resources_
        |       |                     | setting.xml
        |       |--Test
        |--database.mv.db
```

I'm using zenjava JavaFX plugin so the configurations inside the pom.xml are :

```
 <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>main.MainApplication</mainClass>

                    <jfxMainAppJarName>entrepriseLimited.jar</jfxMainAppJarName>
                    <vendor>myCompany</vendor>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- required before build-native -->
                        <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-native</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-native</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

After executing build-jar & build-native goals,i don't find the **"database.mv.db"** File, how can i tell maven to put "database.mv.db" inside 
$basedir ?. Instead if i can put database.mv.db inside the resources file, and this don't prevent me to write to, it's better (Because as i know we can't write to a file inside .jar package)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, dislaimer: **I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin**

To answer our question, you might want to upgrade to the current version of the javafx-maven-plugin and use the special `<additionalAppResouces>`-property, which requires some path, where all your additional files are stored.

So please put your `database.mv.db` into some folder, lets say `src/main/database` and add this to your plugin-configuration:
`<additionalAppResouces>src/main/database</additionalAppResouces>`.

If you want to have that file being copied while calling `mvn jfx:run` or `mvn jfx:jar` too, please add this to your plugin-configuration: `<copyAdditionalAppResourcesToJar>true</copyAdditionalAppResourcesToJar>`

While answering this question, I found that this property (which is available very long time), does not have any example-project inside `src/it` (where all test-projects are stored), sorry for this.